# XGBoost error - When categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I have four categorial features and a fifth numerical one (Var5).  When I try the following code:

```
cat_attribs = ['var1','var2','var3','var4']

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'), cat_attribs)], remainder = 'passthrough')
X_train = full_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=20, verbosity=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following error message when the model tries to make its predictions:

> ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical.  When
> categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter
> `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

In case it's helpful, here is a small sample of the X_train data and the y_train data:

```
       Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4        Var5
1507856   JP  2009  6581  OME  325.787218
839624    FR  2018  5783  I_S   11.956326
1395729   BE  2015  6719  OME   42.888565
1971169   DK  2011  3506  RPP   70.094146
1140120   AT  2019  5474  NMM  270.082738
```

and:

```
          Ind_Var
1507856   8.013558
839624    4.105559
1395729   7.830077
1971169  83.000000
1140120  51.710526
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a small sample of your data.

Comment: @Flavia sure, just added

Comment: You probably have at least one columne with dtype `category`. xgboost then expects the values to be integers and `enable_categorical` set to True in the instantiation of `XGBRegressor`. Source: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/categorical.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have encoded the categorical features in `X_train` but not in `X_test`, and therefore when you run `model.predict(X_test)` you get an error message. In order to fix this problem, at first you need to fit the encoder to `X_train`, and then use the encoder to transform both `X_train` and `X_test`. See the code below for an example.

```
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# define the input data
df = pd.DataFrame([
 {'Var1': 'JP', 'Var2': 2009, 'Var3': 6581, 'Var4': 'OME', 'Var5': 325.787218, 'Ind_Var': 8.013558},
 {'Var1': 'FR', 'Var2': 2018, 'Var3': 5783, 'Var4': 'I_S', 'Var5': 11.956326, 'Ind_Var': 4.105559},
 {'Var1': 'BE', 'Var2': 2015, 'Var3': 6719, 'Var4': 'OME', 'Var5': 42.888565, 'Ind_Var': 7.830077},
 {'Var1': 'DK', 'Var2': 2011, 'Var3': 3506, 'Var4': 'RPP', 'Var5': 70.094146, 'Ind_Var': 83.000000},
 {'Var1': 'AT', 'Var2': 2019, 'Var3': 5474, 'Var4': 'NMM', 'Var5': 270.082738, 'Ind_Var': 51.710526}
])

# extract the features and target
X_train, y_train = df.iloc[:3, :-1], df.iloc[:3, -1]
X_test, y_test = df.iloc[3:, :-1], df.iloc[3:, -1]

# one-hot encode the categorical features
cat_attribs = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_attribs)], remainder='passthrough')

encoder = full_pipeline.fit(X_train)
X_train = encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)

# train the model
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=20, verbosity=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# extract the training set predictions
model.predict(X_train)
# array([7.0887003, 3.7923286, 7.0887003], dtype=float32)

# extract the test set predictions
model.predict(X_test)
# array([7.0887003, 7.0887003], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to deal with the categorial data in xgboost is to specify the type of categorical data in dataframe as

```
cat_attribs = ['var1','var2','var3','var4']
X_train[cat_attribs] = X_train[cat_attribs].astype('category')
X_test[cat_attribs] = X_test[cat_attribs].astype('category')
```

Then in `XGBRegressor` pass `enable_categorical=True`

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=20, enable_categorical=True, verbosity=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

A robust way to achieve the same:

```
# Create a mapping of labels to encoded values from X_train
training_encoded_mapping = X_train['var1'].astype('category').cat.codes
training_encoded_mapping = dict(zip(X_train['var1'].cat.categories, training_encoded_mapping))
X_train['var1'] = X_train['var1'].astype('category').cat.codes

# Apply the mapping to X_test
X_test['var1'] = X_test['var1'].map(training_encoded_mapping)
# Do the same for other vars as well
```

And now don't pass `enable_categorical=True` in model initialization.

For more details, visit the [official docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html).

Answer (score 1):

Enable categorical as one of the input parameters.

xgb = XGBClassifier(random_state=1,eval_metric='logloss',enable_categorical=True)